# How to make a list of xml tags with javaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I need to create the following part of xml file with javaxb :

```
    <tag> ..... </tag> 
    <foto_1> ... </foto_1>
    <foto_2> ... </foto_2>
    <foto_3> ... </foto_3>
    <foto_4> ... </foto_4>
    .....
```

Where the tag  is dynamic, so it could be a number between 1 and 15. 
I asked the receiver if it is possible to make a tag list, but it is not !

Is it possible to create in javaxb this type of list ? 
Or better, i don't know what to write in --> @XmlElement(name="") of the getter method.

Comment: Don’t make a different tag for each identical data item.  Use repetitions of a `<foto>` element, and bind them to a List or array in a JAXB class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution with an @XmlAnyElement-annotated property that returns the elements as JAXBElements:

```
private List<Foto> foto = ...;

@XmlAnyElement
public List<JAXBElement<Foto>> getFoto() {
List<JAXBElement<Foto>> elements = new ArrayList<JAXBElement<Foto>>();
for (Foto current : foto ) 
    elements.add(new JAXBElement(new QName("foto_" + current.getValue(), 
                                 Foto.class, current);
return elements;
}
```

I think is not a clean solution, but it works ! 
I hope it could be useful